# How to delete items from one table on the click on same item in another table using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have two tables, when I check a item in first table it adds into second table, and this part is working perfectly. Now, I want to delete the same item from second table when I un check it from first table. I am using CoreData

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using core data the object should be deleted from the context and from both tables.
Make sure you are implementing those functions in your tables:

```
 - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
     [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  }


   - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
       atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

switch(type) {
    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
   }
  }


  - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
   atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
  newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

switch(type) {

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
        [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
                atIndexPath:indexPath];
        break;

    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                         withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        break;
     }
 }


  - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
     [self.tableView endUpdates];
  }
```

Comment: I only want to delete data from second table, it should not be deleted from first table.

Comment: This is not what you asked in your question. please explain yourself better and  I will try to help.